# std::sort results in a segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17

I wrote a program that counts the number of occurrences of strings using a `std::unordered_map`, then copies the values from the map to a `std::vector` and calls `std::sort` to sort them first by counts, then by string.

See the code below. Please, excuse the long list of strings. I couldn't quickly find a shorter list that would reproduce the behavior.

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfoHVtQL1jQTFkTFxibYNTS257SO9Yf1lg5UAlLaoXsTI7BzmCWHI3lgA1CYJbl4MJFjEmOgA%2BixMyYfYJhoAgpvbu5gHRwBuNUTEDyerzMWwYOy8%2B0ObjEwBIhAQLEBLzeYI%2BXzcCgIxDCwCRrxeYQIe1uYQghL2jWAyFIe2QCEaACoGRTiMBvvMDgB2KwvPZ7THoEAgE5nOKXG53KFAvl8gVCzHYoykaUywkqh57AhxFgKQ48/HPWUEQUgX4OEhQtAMTG0%2BnEBkasLJLxEkzcoHmMwACUwTHQnuVyLMZlQVADHuDABEmA1w0GzBFMAB3XXBwPAsxyADScYzAHVMLnPY1C2mIwnk6mzOnPdmi8G8FWa8GmPWzMALjG22gWMlDABPNtULy0Whthr0QSXNuGf1l%2BPITuOX5t5KYVDJehtgszi4zhhtkjAQyNmOZcf0ghthCedBN8vaZbEZi0RuI%2BcZrsfz2Ee/x37EIO37BggvpNG2ADyKxtuEKZ9muxB/p%2BDBztW5b4MAhBiKuxAYF4DhIT%2BqIQqWaHxgoqBsIeYbAWYBCgW2LBpFetGpEmcTDmOtFsPgra0dExCzoRDYHrR9Gkc2ZjYEYr4KAgbYKGuTAANY4m2SYkLQgoXhJ5YACp4GwwlmHpDG0UIJzoEwQFkRmBlGfuqGSaZunxhZom2Z6nZ0mptEJBojF0K%2BAiruum6uRmvp0upmCYMpbaRpgimEBFnr4FQVBimCSVtmEM4QngjBrI53ayIwLGecGT5tgJQm7qlwYnClTnltENmSXxlVmD2LCEGwgjjqguUoZga4jQNtGPisL5vheX5dVa4QEYe0G0cgXiYpRcRVuqnKRnqHq8ns/DEHsEBWjadKMvyWJ7CAexOi6HJuvqMoHJY1hasQOomAArBYCp/ftCSvVy%2B3Ikdcqmn8FpHFDfZ4ACcPGvKWI4uQA0JI8WN7KKSOg3jAB0FxKMQvwQF9OqE%2BkABemAQPM8wHUdJ1nRdRJMC6Q1mAAbAc/2atqNIMPzkZ3YL30KEzR18kTmC9gYaxXNETDIMpFNCwwTMg4dho3SaFFNBAROxJhDAMzScsoRbKp8n9Vi/ZG50CDanNEOYfNMDS7MUlzHt7NEHIALQatEqCeFyoNvXgVBnUw1M1AI6BfNgAcJ1a6AchcBDTZqxBeIWOsyzK2e5/HNCIa6RxpxXmLM3rdt7Sq2v6m6kYcIstCcL9vB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1j8k%2BazvQkPCkAQmgd4sykgL9Gj6Jwki9/Pg%2BcLwCggKvc/9x3pBwLAMCICglHJHQcTkJQPbX/Q8TAFwGhcHwdBfXvEDRFv0RhI0fsnAZ49XKhBBgtAgFH1IFgW4Ml1gD3wBcWovw97QMwKoGoLoEG8EJJgLu0DXy1UAh4LAW80YsGAcfKgBhgAKAAGqFSTBBMaVCZCCBEGIdgUh2HyCUGoLeuh34GCMCgUelh9B4GiHvSAiwNyOBdpwIOApDiRlMB9SwXBOR7CDnmMQtAdEQTMLvfBfxMguBQmMPw78QjTFKOUPQqR0gKKyJ4VojiCguL6PYuYthTGdAYN0UYbjcjvw6C4oJUwSgDAqMMHoVi9CYh6N4mJEhFgURWGsPQWJYpUM7t3Te0Ch4cFUP4HmQceaSD2FSZAexX6Ey4GdEeGibB7FwIQEgU9357A8L2G%2Bp1NhcHmLwQ%2BWhGakCXivNeHAN6kEoTzAAnITMpUhp7%2BE5BoHmizOS/VIH3AexTd771nvPRYp8L7LAIM6Agd8ICXA6diQU79%2BAcNEOIHhLy%2BEqHUNAoRpAkyCWSHk6ZPc9lb2KVBK5Lpcax1KeUyp1TkC1PqY0iAvTH5xC6cMk5R9xmgT9IMC2BDZmUP8g0hI/hfo838FwMwCyEj%2BTMFSsFRSd62GOaMheEzl6rwIQkQpBy2WcvGQQ4xLLBUcBGacxYAF0jOEkEAA%3D%3D) concurs the segfault for GCC 10 and above.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something obvious here?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::unordered_map<
    std::string,
    int
  > terms;

  std::vector<const char*> input {
"Head", "of", "Data", "News", "UK", "We", "are", "News", "UK", "is", "a",
"great", "company", "full", "talented", "and", "creative", "people", "We",
"are", "an", "organisation", "that", "holds", "journalism", "at", "its",
"very", "heart", "Our", "newspapers", "and", "digital", "products",
"include", "some", "of", "the", "most", "powerful", "media", "brands", "in",
"the", "English", "speaking", "world:", "the", "Times", "The", "Sunday",
"Times", "and", "The", "Sun", "reaching", "30", "million", "people", "each",
"week", "Despite", "differences", "in", "audience", "and", "content", "our",
"brands", "are", "united", "by", "a", "commitment", "to", "independent",
"journalism", "that", "connects", "our", "customers"
  };

  for (const char* str : input) {
    ++terms[str];
  }

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> order;
  order.reserve(terms.size());
  for (const auto& [ term, n ] : terms)
    order.emplace_back(term,n);

  std::sort(order.begin(), order.end(),
    [](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool {
      if (a.second > b.second) return true;
      return a.first < b.first;
    }
  );
}
```

Here's the output from gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcmp_evex_movbe () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcmp-evex-movbe.S:118
118     VMOVU_MASK (%rsi), %YMM2{%k2}
(gdb) bt
#0  __memcmp_evex_movbe () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcmp-evex-movbe.S:118
#1  0x00007ffff7d4d7ad in std::char_traits<char>::compare (__n=<optimized out>, __s2=<optimized out>, __s1=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h:385
#2  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare (this=<optimized out>, __str=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:3148
#3  0x000055555555b408 in std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (__lhs="Data", __rhs=<error: Cannot access memory at address 0x72656d6f74737563>)
    at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:3694
#4  0x00005555555573e2 in operator()<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > (__closure=0x7fffffffd9f7, a={...}, b={...}) at test.cc:108
#5  0x000055555555744b in __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >::operator()<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >) (this=0x7fffffffd9f7, __val={...},
  __it={first = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x72656d6f74737563>, second = 2449}) at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:240
#6  0x0000555555557096 in std::__unguarded_linear_insert<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >) (__last={first = "", second = 3}, __comp=...) at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1789
#7  0x0000555555556c28 in std::__unguarded_insertion_sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >) (__first={first = "an", second = 1}, __last={first = "", second = 0}, __comp=...) at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1830
#8  0x000055555555695b in std::__final_insertion_sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >) (__first={first = "", second = 3}, __last={first = "", second = 0}, __comp=...) at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1850
#9  0x0000555555556806 in std::__sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >) (__first={first = "", second = 3}, __last={first = "", second = 0}, __comp=...) at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1940
#10 0x0000555555556751 in std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, main(int, char**)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >, struct {...}) (__first={first = "", second = 3}, __last={first = "", second = 0}, __comp=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4853
#11 0x000055555555665c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfc8) at test.cc:105
```

Comment: Does the problem still occur if `input` is an array of const char*? How about if it is a vector of strings?

Comment: I haven't sussed out the details of *why* this causes the segfault, but your comparator is implemented incorrectly. It should only be using the fallback comparison when the first comparison is equal. Changing the first line to `if (a.second != b.second) return a.second > b.second;` fixes it. I'm assuming the underlying problem is the inconsistent ordering means the invariants expected in sorting aren't adhered to and something goes terribly wrong. Alternatively, change the body of the function to `return std::tie(-a.second, a.first) < std::tie(-b.second, b.first);` and let `tuple` handle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    [](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool {
      if (a.second > b.second) return true;
      return a.first < b.first;
    }
```

This comparator function violates the requirement for being a strict weak ordering comparator. I am going to use two `int` values for clarity, rather than an int and a string, because this makes the problem easier to understand, but the same thing happens if one of the values is a string. For the purposes of this explanation comparing two int values has the same semantics as comparing two `std::string`s.

So, for example, with the following two values:

```
   a={2, 4}
   b={1, 2}
```

The first one will compare to be less than the second one. `4 > 2` and the comparator returns true.

```
   a={1, 2}
   b={2, 4}
```

Same thing here. `2 > 4` is false, but `1 < 2` is true, so the comparator returns true as well.

End result: here you have two values, and each one is less than the other one.

As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Spot on. Also a concise description of the problem.  Unfortunately the rubriks on these questions rarely aligns with their cause. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order  The Concept is new, the concept is old as time itself.

Comment: Fascinating. ;)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I agree. The problem is that the question cannot be framed in the right context a priori, because if it could be, the solution would have been obvious. If anyone has a suggestion for adding the right context to the question post factum, feel free to edit it.

Comment: The context is correct. A bad comparator is a known reason for a typical `std::sort` implementation to segfault. Whenever I see someone complaining about a crash that involves `std::sort` and nothing immediately stands out, it's always a busted comparator logic.

Answer (score 2):

As it was pointed to the comparison does not satisfy the requirement of the strict weak ordering.

You can resolve the problem using the standard function `std::tie` declared in the header `<utility>` the following way

```
  std::sort(order.begin(), order.end(),
    [](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool {
        return std::tie( b.second, a.first ) < std::tie( a.second, b.first );
    } );
```

After that the first 10 sorted records will look like

```
and 4
are 3
the 3
News 2
The 2
Times 2
UK 2
We 2
a 2
brands 2
```

Pay attention to that upper case letters precede lower case letters in the lexicographical order.

Comment: tie is useful. as is pair and tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator function does not reflect your sorting criterion. In general, when you have a tuple as the sort key, such as (ke1, key2), key2 is compared if and only if there is a tie for key1. So your comparator function must reflect the `tie` as a pre-condition when you compare key2. So in general, your comparator would look like:

```
if (a.key1 < a.key1) return true;
if (a.key1 == a.key1) /* tie case for key1 */ 
    return a.key2 < b.key2;
return false;
```

So your comparator may be changed to

```
[](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool {
    if (a.second > b.second) return true;  
    if (a.second == b.second)  // This reflects a tie for key1 
        return a.first < b.first;
    return false;
}
```